# One huge xml file - best approach in Spark

Tags: xml, databricks

I receive a really huge xml file which is zipped and called vehiclesdata.zip
I unzip it and it's around 110 GB (!) and still just one single file.
I've succesfully read the xml data into a dataframe in Databricks and then saved it in parquet format instead. But it's a very slow process. If I choose a more powerfull cluster it speeds up the process.
I just wonder what will be the best approach in Spark to process the file faster.
Should I first split the file into smaller xml files e.g. 220 files on 0.5 GB each?
I've made a job for that in Spark using multiprocessing, but it does not use the nodes in the cluster. Multiprocessing only runs on the driver node.

Answer (score 1):

I've processed the xml file in scala in MS Fabric with the default spark pool that comes with the free Fabric trial. It only took about 16 minutes to parse the xml into a dataframe and then write it as parquet. It seems much faster than what I have experienced on databricks. I'll do some more testing on databricks to see if I can get the same result there.